# Select records using WHERE clause on comma delimited field

Tags: php

I have a table myTable with 2 fields (4 example):

```
ID   Zip_Codes
===  =========
1    60148,60123,61034,61234
2    60122,61034
```

I want to use:

```
$zip = 61034;
$qry = "Select ID from myTable Where $zip in Zip_Codes";
```

Is that possible?
What makes it fast?
Other better solution?

Comment: *Other better solution ?* = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization - don't store multiple values in a single field

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `IN` here.  `x IN (1,2)` is shorthand for `x = 1 OR x = 2`, it doesn't let you search inside a comma separated list.

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(61034, Zip_Codes);
```

Though, you shouldn't have multiple values in one row.  You should have one row per zip code.

```
RowID   ID   Zip_Code
=====   ===  =========
1       1    60148
2       1    60123
3       1    61034
4       1    61234
5       2    60122
6       2    61034
```

(`RowID` would the primary key.  You could add an `INDEX` to `ID`.)

Then you can simply do:

```
SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE Zip_Code = 61034
```

Comment: Thanks. Performance is important. It that ok solution, any better ones that put speed into account.

Comment: @user1538401: A better solution would to not have multiple values in one field.  Have one row for each zip code.